# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null when submitting a form

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a webpage in which I am trying to get an input and submit a form using that input. But the code below gives an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null"

```
<script>
    function SetMissingDataReason1(){
        var reasons = prompt("Please enter a reason for missing data","Not collected");
        document.getElementById('reason1').value = reasons;
        document.getElementById('missingdataform1').submit();
    }
</script>
<form action='projectchecklist.php' method='post' id='missingdataform1'>
<input type='hidden' name='action' value='setmissingdatareason'>
<input type='hidden' name='projectid' value='124'>
<input type='hidden' name='enrollmentid' value='22636'>
<input type='hidden' name='projectchecklistid' value='9'>
<input type='hidden' name='reason' id='reason1'>
</form>
<a href='#' onClick='SetMissingDataReason1();'>?</a>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You might want to camel-Case your ids. e.g: `missingDataForm1`. I'm not sure if I can give an answer for this, because I'm not that skilled with javascript.

Comment: Hint: `null.submit()` will give you the same error.

Comment: your code works on my end

Comment: Everything looks fine here also.

Comment: I just checked, your code it's fine. It's working . . . maybe show me the PHP file.

Comment: I think I figured it out. This section of code exists within another form. I have a table which has a checkbox on each row and a submit button at the bottom. Each row as the above code within it. So its a nested form. Apparently javascript doesn't like that. When I run the above code by itself it works as expected. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @GregB  You should probably show us your PHP file.